# EditText Lost Focus When Keyboard Suggestion Appears

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, suggestbox

I have a problem with my android application.

I have a EditText in a ListView. When I focus the EditText, keyboard appears (normally) but when the keyboard suggestions appears I lost focused and I can't focus in a more.

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: Try using the same EditText outside of the ListView, I've found that placing an EditText inside a ListView is asking for trouble, they generally do not play well.